# Python - read json object over TCP connection (using regex?)

Tags: python, json, tcp

My client sends json objects over TCP. Each object is with the following form:

```
{
       "message" => "{\"timestamp\":\"2016-07-21T01:20:04.392799-0400\",\"in_iface\":\"docker0\",\"event_type\":\"alert\",\"src_ip\":\"172.17.0.2\",\"dest_ip\":\"172.17.0.3\",\"proto\":\"ICMP\",\"icmp_type\":0,\"icmp_code\":0,\"alert\":{\"action\":\"allowed\",\"gid\":2,\"signature_id\":2,\"rev\":0,\"signature\":\"ICMP msg\",\"category\":\"\",\"severity\":3},\"payload\":\"hFuQVwAA\",\"payload_printable\":\"kk\"}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-25T04:41:11.980Z",
          "path" => "/etc/logstash/jsonSample.log",
          "host" => "baklava",
           "doc" => {
                "timestamp" => "2016-07-21T01:20:04.392799-0400",
                 "in_iface" => "docker0",
               "event_type" => "alert",
                   "src_ip" => "172.17.0.2",
                  "dest_ip" => "172.17.0.3",
                    "proto" => "ICMP",
                "icmp_type" => 0,
                "icmp_code" => 0,
                    "alert" => {
                  "action" => "allowed",
                     "gid" => 2,
            "signature_id" => 2,
                     "rev" => 0,
               "signature" => "ICMP msg",
                "category" => "",
                "severity" => 3
        },
                  "payload" => "hFuQVwAA",
        "payload_printable" => "kk"
    },
     "alert.gid" => 2,
          "tags" => [
        [0] "tagName_2"
    ]
}
```

I'd like to write a python server that listent to port 11111 , and is able to get such objects and parse them seperately.

Can anyone help with a complete code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note, that this platform is no coding service with batteries included. Try for your own, show us your code, get help and retry. This way you'll be learning as you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) package. The documentation gives small examples which may be useful for you. Here is an extended example for a tcp server:

```
import SocketServer
import os
import logging
import json

FORMAT = '[%(asctime)-15s] %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.DEBUG)


class MyServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    # By setting this we allow the server to re-bind to the address by
    # setting SO_REUSEADDR, meaning you don't have to wait for
    # timeouts when you kill the server and the sockets don't get
    # closed down correctly.
    allow_reuse_address = True

    request_queue_size = 10

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.host = os.uname()[1]
        self.port = port

        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, (self.host,self.port), MyTCPHandler)

        logging.info( "Server has been started on {h}:{p}".format(h=self.host,p=self.port) )


class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        # max length is here 2048 chars
        s = self.request.recv(2048).strip()

        logging.info( "received: {d}".format(d=s) )

        # here you may parse the received string
        obj = json.loads( s )

        # here just send something back to server 
        self.request.sendall("got it")


PORT = 11111

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 11111
    #server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server = MyServer( PORT )

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flaskRESTful. Feel free to dig into the docs: http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/

Especially the full example gives you enough information to achieve your goal: (http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/quickstart.html#full-example)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

TODOS = {
    'todo1': {'task': 'build an API'},
    'todo2': {'task': '?????'},
    'todo3': {'task': 'profit!'},
}


def abort_if_todo_doesnt_exist(todo_id):
    if todo_id not in TODOS:
        abort(404, message="Todo {} doesn't exist".format(todo_id))

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('task')


# Todo
# shows a single todo item and lets you delete a todo item
class Todo(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        abort_if_todo_doesnt_exist(todo_id)
        return TODOS[todo_id]

    def delete(self, todo_id):
        abort_if_todo_doesnt_exist(todo_id)
        del TODOS[todo_id]
        return '', 204

    def put(self, todo_id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        task = {'task': args['task']}
        TODOS[todo_id] = task
        return task, 201


# TodoList
# shows a list of all todos, and lets you POST to add new tasks
class TodoList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return TODOS

    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        todo_id = int(max(TODOS.keys()).lstrip('todo')) + 1
        todo_id = 'todo%i' % todo_id
        TODOS[todo_id] = {'task': args['task']}
        return TODOS[todo_id], 201

##
## Actually setup the Api resource routing here
##
api.add_resource(TodoList, '/todos')
api.add_resource(Todo, '/todos/<todo_id>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```